# PHPUnit: Flat XML to BIT(1) is always 1

Tags: phpunit

I am trying to run PHPUnit tests and I have a problem with putting a false (0) into a BIT(1) column.

My XML looks like (without pasting my entire XML File):

```
<!-- Panama -->
    <ztest_user
            id="3"
            firstname="Eddie"
            lastname="Van Halen"
            password="dabac4cd92d71106e74406be137a578e1b3ce436420f66d2df5be458301d2154"
            salt="zU`Rr$X=YjxHRp8o"
            email="eddie@vanhalen.com"
            roleid="2"
            date_added=""
            date_modified=""
            enabled="1"
            confirmed="0"
            graduationyear="2020"
            yearjoined="2019"
            birthday="1955-01-26"
            profileimageid=""
    />
```

When I run the tests, this entry gets put into the database as shown, except for the confirmed column, which gets a 1 instead of a 0.

My thoughts are that the BIT(1) column gets set if there is any data and not to what the value of confirmed actually is.

How should I go about fixing this?

Comment: I should note that confirmed is NOT a nullable column, so deleting the confirmed attribute and setting the default value to 0 in MySQL throws a schema error

Comment: I also converted the XML to YAML and the results are the same. Inserts a 1 instead of a 0.